Making Google Sheets Match Function work for more than one row
I wrote this google sheets function, if there is letter L in e2 then it writes -1 in g2, when there is different letter it finds text from c2 in O2:O15 column and writes  number from Q2:Q15 column that is in row where c2 text was found right into g2 cell
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("L"; E2; 0));-1;INDEX($Q$2:$Q$15; MATCH(C2&E2;$O$2:$O$15&$S$2:$S;0)))

It works as expected on G2 cell, however once I drag the function down so it works on other cells (g3,g4 and so on) error occurs. I'm not sure how I can fix this, help would be appreciated.
Edit: thanks for your answers however they didn't function as expected. But since I managed to make it somewhat work using this formula I'll stick to it for now
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("L"; E2; 0));-1;INDEX($Q$2:$Q$15; MATCH(C2;$O$2:$O$15;0)))


what says the error?

"Error analyzing formula"

can you share a copy of your sheet?

try:
=IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("L"; E2; )); -1; INDEX($Q$2:$Q$15; MATCH(C2; $O$2:$O$15; ))))

but better not drag your formula and use arrays:
=MAP(C2:C10; E2:E10; LAMBDA(ccc; eee; 
 IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("L"; eee; )); -1; INDEX(Q2:Q15; MATCH(ccc; O2:O15; ))))


it did return what seems like random number. Hovewer removing e2 from MATCH(C2&E2) part (so the formula now is  =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("L"; E2; 0));-1;INDEX($Q$2:$Q$15; MATCH(C2;$O$2:$O$15;0)))  ) seems to work now. It's not perfect since I wanted for it to wait for E column text before writing something to G column but I can work with it
